# Asp.net  .ashx error in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, httphandler

I am trying to shift my asp.net 3.5 application (C#) to sharepoint.
I have used one .ashx(web handler) file for multiple file upload control in my application
Now it works perfectly locally in asp.net but when i do the same thing with sharepoint with no change in code it stops working.

I dont know if i need to add some dll or any supportive file to get that file upload page (using .ashx file) working in sharepoint

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your are not adding your handler to sharepoint's  web.config ...

like

see my post for what i did to make it work [Custom Httphandler in SharePoint](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/04/create-and-deploy-custom-httphandler-in.html)